# Chosen Search Box in SharePoint Classic View

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

```js
<script src="https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script>

// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function ()  
{
    $(SPUtility.GetSPField('Owner Name').Controls).find('select').chosen({width: "350px"});

    console.log("test");
    
    var cascadeArray = new Array();
        
        //filter
        cascadeArray.push({
            parentFormField: "Owner", //Display name on form of field from parent list
            childList: "Vessel", //List name of child list
            childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
            childFormField: "Vessel Name", //Display name on form of the child field
            parentFieldInChildList: "Owner Name", //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
            //firstOptionText: "< Select a Claim Activity Type >"
        });
        $().HillbillyCascade(cascadeArray);
}); 

</script>
```

I have problem, when I create script for chosen in the drop down in the search field, this does not work in the SharePoint Classic view that I have. Can I have another solution for this from the script side. Because my script cannot working but when before doing the migration the script went well. The drop down that I have is on the lookup filter that I have done on other SharePoint lists. Thanks

Comment: Please update your post with a) your script (or at least representative portions), b) what did you "migrate"?, and c) more detail about exactly "what's not working" :(

Comment: Hi @paulsm4, please check my script. before I migrated this script was working

Comment: Sorry: I don't see anything "wrong" in your script. That's unsurprising: you said "it used to work".  Q: What changed?  You "migrated" from one version of SP to another?  To exactly what SP version?  STRONG SUGGESTION: run your script in Chrome Developer Tools, and look for any JS errors ("red", in the "console" tab).

Comment: Hi @paulsm4 My case has been solved. There is something wrong in writing "Ower Name" to "Owner_x0020_Name" and there are a few additions to the script on: $(SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Owner_x0020_Name').Dropdown).chosen({width: '300px'});